# How to return result of asynchronous json request

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlsession

I have a method that returns a string usually locally, but with a backup from the Web. I was retrieving some JSON using dataWithContentsOfUrl but want to switch to using a Session object which is better for the UI and also--if I am not mistaken--allows the server to set a sessionId on the phone, however, I'm struggling with the async issue.

With the old code, I just returned the JSON but I'm struggling with how to do this for the asynchronous result. I can't change the calling method which returns a string.  What can I do with the asynchronous Api call to use the data that is retrieved?

async:

```
-(void)getAsyncAnswerFor:(NSString*) str {
    NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://~.com//api.php?q=%@",str];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  //HOW DO I PASS THIS BACK TO THE CALLING METHOD OR IS THAT IMPOSSIBLE
                                          }];

    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

sync

```
-(NSString*)getAnswerFor:(NSString*) str {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://~.com//api.php?q=%@",str];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:surl]];
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
   //process JSON
    if (error) {
    return @"";
    }
    return @"processed JSON";
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

If what I want to do is totally impossible, is it possible to set a sessionID on the phone without the Session object?  I know setting a session ID is is not the greatest approach, but I'm trying to avoid a lot of authentication overhead.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking several questions, but to your code-comment, you could pass a block to the `getAsyncAnswerFor` that you can then call from the dataTaskWithUrl's completion handler. From there you could pass back the `data`, `response` and `error`.

Comment: how would I pass back the data?

Comment: By calling the `block` that you pass as a parameter to your async function.

Comment: There are lots of examples out there for how to use blocks. But you might want to start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html. Check out the section entitled: "You Can Pass Blocks as Arguments to Methods or Functions"

Comment: I’ve based a blog post around this and similar questions: http://www.programmingios.net/2019/03/09/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to your asynchronous function and then call it when the url session completion handler is called. This is a trivial example:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithBlock:(void (^)(double, double))block {
    ...
    block(21.0, 2.0);
}
```

I lifted this ^^ from the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) but you might be able to do something like this: (Note: I didn't check this in a compiler!)

```
-(void)getAsyncAnswerFor:(NSString*) str completion:(void (^)(NSData, NSURLResponse, NSError))block {
    NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://~.com//api.php?q=%@",str];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                          dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                             block(data, response, error);
                                          }];

    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

You'll need to be careful if you try to reference `self` anywhere in the blocks.

Comment: The tricky thing here was that the original calling method was a synchronous function that has to return something.  My conclusion is there is no way to return anything from the asynchronous method through that chain.  So what I'm doing is returning nil in the calling function.  Then after the fact, using code such as yours I update the UI when the asynchronous method is done.